# Save variables until redirected back on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am currently making a donation page for something and I am currently struggeling with one of the last features left to be implemented.

Basically what I want is that people enter their skype username, they click a link to go to PayPal, once they paid they get redirected back and all their donation data (which is received from PayPal's IPN System) gets inserted into a MySQL Database. The problem is that I don't know how to temporarily store their skype username to add to a database after the donation is done.

Can anyone help my with my problem? If someone needs my code please just reply ;)

Comment: You could use a session.

Comment: I'm kinda a noob when it comes to these PHP special things like Sessions, etc. Mind Explaining? And about the possible duplicate, i'm not sending any data to Paypal what then should be returned back through the custom variable. Maybe this is the best thing to do after all?

Comment: I decided to rewrite some stuff and made it work the way it works in the duplicate. Thanks for your help!